# XMPPFramework - Online User List Not Showing in Openfire Server

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I have created a chat app using XMPPFramework and Openfire server. I've created multiple user accounts in Openfire administrator console and I can login to those user accounts but the problem is that they're not showing other users in the online/offline list.

I tested with talk.google.com server and it shows all online users in a list.

In my iPhone app, it's not even showing both online and offline users list.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my mistake I had added all users into a group. And then its started listing the online user's list.

We should create a bond between various users like in gmail by adding user to contact